# How to know if device sensor managers(orientation) is working properly?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

My device has orientation problem from few days. I asked question on stackexchange site and here its link :- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50621/horizontal-layout-issue-in-samsung-galaxy-s

My question is that is there any way so I can find that my device's sensors are working correctly? (orientation in this case) so I can be sure that its not hardware issue/ defect in hardware.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you put it in a flat area it should give 0 for all acceleration values since it's not moving/rotating in any direction

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I hope you have read my original question on stackexchange by given link, As I said there Horizontal calibration is working. Does this mean device hardware is working properly?

Comment: when you change orientation of it does that values change?